# Neo4j Deleting disconnected graphs based on number of relations

Tags: neo4j

I have a graph, well, a series of disconnected graphs in Neo4j.

I want to delete all nodes that is only connected to one other node.

So I want to get rid of the pairs, but keep all graphs that have at least 3 nodes connected in some way.

I'm using the get or create method when enterting the data so it should all be indexed.

Comment: Are you using Spring Data Neo4j? Is there more then one type of object (nodeEntity)? How many nodes do you approximately have in your database? These things would be helpful to know.

Comment: No, no, and a very small number. Around 1,000 and 1,500 relations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using Cypher, you can achieve your task with this query:

```
start a=node(*) 
match a-[r]->b 
where length(a--()) = 1 and length(b--()) = 1 
delete a,r,b
```

Here is a link where you can see it in action: http://console.neo4j.org/r/1re6t

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting "SyntaxException: illegal start of value
==> "match a-[r]->b where length (a--()) = 1 and length(b--()) = 1""

Comment: I just added a link where you can see the query running live. It will only work on 1.8.M04 and later.

Comment: Oh. Looks like I'm a version early.

Comment: Hmm, well, now the query executes just fine, but it doesn't change the data at all. Using return instead of delete gets me 0 rows back. Hmm. Could the problem be that there are two relationships per pair? There is one relationship going from each node to the other. I changed the 1s to 2s and it seems to have worked, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Your link gives me "Error: illegal value "where length(a--()) = 1 and length(b--()) = 1 ".

Answer (score 0):

This is just a solution which I came up with in short time. So it's probably not the best one, but I hope you get the idea and may adapt it to your case.

```
TraversalDescription td = Traversal.description().depthFirst().evaluator(new Evaluator() {
        @Override
        public Evaluation evaluate(Path path) {
            if (path.length() == 1) {
                int count = 0;
                Iterator<Relationship> it = path.endNode().getRelationships().iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    it.next();
                    count++;
                }
                if (count == 1) {
                    count = 0;
                    it = path.startNode().getRelationships().iterator();
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        it.next();
                        count++;
                    }
                    if (count == 1) {
                        return Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_PRUNE;
                    } else {
                        return Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_PRUNE;
                    }
                } else {
                    return Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_PRUNE;
                }
            }
            return Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
        }
    });

    Traverser traverser = td.traverse(**MYNODE**);
```

This traversal description should return all paths, which contain only 2 nodes. I haven't tested it, but the idea is: It checks if the start- and the endnode of a path (lenght 1) has more than one relationships. If so, it cannot be the end of a path, and is therefore not in a pair. Otherwise it will be returned by the traverser later on. For information on the traversals, check the [neo4j documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-traversal.html).

With your current database layout, you would have to execute the traverser for every node in your database. This is normally a bad way to do, because it does so much unnecessary iterations. If you only do this once, it may be a solution for the moment. If you want to integrate this functionality in your final application, I'd suggest adding a few relationships (connecting each cluster to the root node).

You could add a relationship from the root node (id=0) to each node in your database. From the root node, you then traverse with the traversal-description from above (just change if `(path.length() == 1)` to if `(path.length() == 2)` and remove the count-check on the startnode). You would then get all paths with a pair at once with one traversal. This is much faster. You could even remove the relationships afterwards. Basically you can design your relationships the way you want, you can always ignore specific ones in a query or traversal. But you need them sometimes, to get better performance and easier traversal descriptions.

Hope it gives you some ideas.